# Hidden Markov Model prior

Tags: hidden-markov-model

Suppose I have a set of time sequences, and that each time sequence is representative of a class.

I can train several HMMs using Baum-Welch, one HMM per class.  Let all HMMs have the same number of states, and the same allowable transitions between certain states.  In other words the model selection is already done.

If a forward pass through the HMM can give the probability of a testing sequence being generated by a certain HMM, how do I use this to assign a class label?

I think that Baum-Welch may over-fit more for certain classes, and therefore that a prior should be introduced.

Could a good prior be the best set of N constant coefficients multiplying the output probabilities of each of the N HMMs for each class that would in training maximize the the correct class labels being assigned?

And secondly, what is the most fair way to train the HMMs for all classes so that one HMM for a certain class doesn't over-fit more than the HMMs for other classes?